# Wrap spans inside a table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have this table, I try to wrap the green span elements (a,b,c,d,e,f) so that all columns have the same width and put the extra spans in extra lines of the same cell increasing the height. As it is now, the first column takes its width from the spans and all are in one line. I tried changing the display and word-wrap options but did nothing.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}
.goods td:nth-child(1){
   color:green;
}
.goods span{
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius:15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:13px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="goods">
    <td><span id="good1">a</span><span id="good2">b</span><span id="good3">c</span><span id="good4">d</span><span id="good5">e</span><span id="good6">f</span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span id="ship">+</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` is inline element by default so you have to change `display` property to `inline-block` for example.

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}
.goods td:nth-child(1){
   color:green;
}
.goods span{
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius:15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:13px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="goods">
    <td><span id="good1">a</span><span id="good2">b</span><span id="good3">c</span><span id="good4">d</span><span id="good5">e</span><span id="good6">f</span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span id="ship">+</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: putting a width on the spans, it puts everyone in a separate line (see updated question). I want to fit as many as I can keeping the same column width.

Comment: I feel ashamed, that was so easy, how did I missed that?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display: inline-block;` in span CSS

```css
body {
  background-color: #444;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  width: 100px;
}
.goods td:nth-child(1){
   color:green;
}
.goods span{
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius:15px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  width:13px;
  cursor:pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table id="main">
  <tr>
    <td>K</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>*</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>*</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="goods">
    <td><span id="good1">a</span><span id="good2">b</span><span id="good3">c</span><span id="good4">d</span><span id="good5">e</span><span id="good6">f</span></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><span id="ship">+</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```